# location.href is not working in if sentence in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanna make easy way of page with password.

in javascript when i use any code with "location"(i tried everything.. replace, asign...etc), it didn't work anything!!!!

but instead of location.href, when i used window.open(), it is perfectly working.
but i wanna stay same window... not new tab or new window...

help me...

In Html

```
<form action="" method="post" name="Please enter the password to continue.">
<div class="WorkPassword">

<input type="password" class="button" id="WorkInputPassword"
name="password" placeholder="Please enter the password"/>

<input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Enter" onClick="goLogin();">
</div>
```

and in javascript.

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'WorkInputPassword' );
var goLogin = function () {

        var password = input.value;

        if (password === '1234') {

            location.href="google.com";

            return false; 

        } else {
            alert( 'check again' );
            input.value = '';
             return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect to a new domain you should use the complete address (including the `http://` or `https://`).

```
location.href="http://google.com";
```

**However** in your case it's not enough, since you are inside a `submit` event of your form, and if you want to cancel that `submit` event you must use `event.preventDefault()` inside the function.

So, it should be something like that:

```
if (password === '1234') {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.href="http://google.com";
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: @ElinJung - "it doesn't work" is no information at all ... check your browser developer tools console and network tabs to see what is occurring and if there are any errors - debugging 101

Comment: @Dekel oh i didn't read all but now i checked it! and it is work!!!!!! 

thanks so much!!!! i am just learning to javascript..but it's baby step.. :)